# Yacc: using a file pointer in the yyparse() method

Tags: c, file, yacc

I would like to write to a specified file in my yyparse method, however I can't seem to access the file pointer in the parse method. 
I keep getting this error.

In this implementation of a yacc, it is fed by a stream of tokens generated by the lexx.yy.c file and handles tokens with specified sections of code.

My code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

extern FILE *fp;

%}



%union {int num; char id;}         /* Yacc definitions */
%start line
%token print
%token exit_command
%token <num> number 
%token <id> identifier
%type <num> line exp term
%type <id> assignment


%%

/* descriptions of expected inputs     corresponding actions (in C) */

line    : assignment ';'                {;}
            | exit_command ';'      {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
            | print exp ';'  {fprintf(fp, "System.out.println();");}
            | line assignment ';'   {;}
            ;

assignment : identifier '=' exp  { updateSymbolVal($1,$3); }
                    ;
exp     : term                  {$$ = $1;}
        | '-' term              {$$ = -$2;}
        | exp '+' term          {$$ = $1 + $3;}
        | exp '-' term          {$$ = $1 - $3;}
        | exp '/' term          {if($1 == 0 & $3 == 0) {y");}


%%                     /* C code */

int computeSymbolIndex(char token)
{
    int idx = -1;
    if(islower(token)) {
            idx = token - 'a' + 26;
    } else if(isupper(token)) {
            idx = token - 'A';
    }
    return idx;
}


int main (void) {
    /* init symbol table */
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
            symbols[i] = 0;
    }

fp = fopen("/home/sufs1/ru7/si/rd019985/Desktop/Mine/file.txt", "a");

yyparse ();
    return 0;
}
```

porque?
P.S 
Just as a note, I've trimmed down the code quite mindlessly, so if you could stick to topic it would be great
P .S .S 
Sorry if this sounds ignorant, I'm a java man

Comment: What if you try just with `FILE *fp;` instead of `extern FILE *fp;`?

Comment: What error do you get? When do you actually write to the file? As anto suggested, or try putting the file in the code section, just below the %% line. As long as you're only ever writing to functions in the code section, you don't need it in the top declarations section.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are really using `bison`, the cleanest way to do this is to supply `fp` as a parameter to `yyparse`, thereby avoiding global variables (for that case; see the section in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl) on "pure parsers" to eliminate the built-in globals.)

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int yylex();
/* The extra parameter is also given to yyerror */
void yyerror(FILE* fp, const char* msg);
%}

%parse-param { FILE* fp }
%union {int num; char id;}
%start line

/* More declarations and grammar ... */

%%

int main (void) {
    // ...
    FILE* fp = fopen("/home/sufs1/ru7/si/rd019985/Desktop/Mine/file.txt", "a");
    yyparse (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

---

For future reference: A question of the form "Why do I get this error message" is much easier to answer if you *actually include the text of the error message* and an indication of where it occurred. In this case, I suspect the error was a linker error complaining that `fp` was not  found, because an `extern` declaration does not actually define the variable (it declares that it is present in some other translation unit.) You could fix that, instead, but I think not using globals is better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, sorry I forgot to paste he error message in. Also rici thanks for maintaining stack overflows reputation for being the website most filled with sarcastic self important comments on the web. I tried your solution, and it didn't work. I fixed the problem by separating the main method into another class and defining command line arguments properly. I was just sort of giving it the file and it worked before. Thanks for the help x

Comment: @GaryCassar: I'm sorry the solution didn't work for you. Care to explain what happened? It certainly works in my code; perhaps I didn't explain it well enough or there is some version mismatch issue. I still don't know what problem you encountered in the first place, but I'm glad you got things working.